# how to adjust the spacing of grid lines in chartist.js?

Tags: javascript, charts, linechart, chartist.js

I am having trouble with `chartist.js`.
I want to adjust the spacing between `y-axis` gridlines by `40px`.(Now 36px)
I tried to find some examples already, but I couldn't.

```
.ct-grids line {
  stroke: #fff;
  opacity: .05;
  stroke-dasharray: none;
}
```

This is my current styling for grids.

```
var data = {
  labels: ['JAN 1', 'JAN 18', 'FEB 14', 'MAR 9', 'APR 22', 'May 2'],
  series: [
  [40.8, 46.5, 48.8, 56.9, 68.7, 72.7],
  [12.8, 13.7, 13.9, 14.8, 15.3, 15.6],
  [5.2, 3.8, 4.2, 5, 3.9, 4.3],
  [1.2, 1.8, 1.7, 2.1, 1.8, 1.9]
  ]
};

var options = {
   showPoint: false,
   lineSmooth: false,
   axisX: {
        showGrid: false,
        showLabel: false
    },
    axisY: {
        offset: 0,
        showGrid: true,
        showLabel: false
    }
};

var chart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data, options);
```

Please let me know if you know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please change the `axisY` option like this.

```
options = {
    axisY: {
        offset: 0,
        scaleMinSpace: 40
        showGrid: true,
        showLabel: false
    }
}
```

For more information, https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/api-documentation.html.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `scaleMinSpace` on the `axisY` option worked for me

```
options = {
    axisY: {
         scaleMinSpace: 40
    }
}
```